# How to deal with joins in django app using GAE?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, model, google-cloud-datastore

In my django application I have essentially joins ("__").  If I were to use Google App Engine, how would my app work in this instance?  From what I've read, Bigtable doesn't allow this.  Any advice on how to work with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: it wouldn't.

You would presumably be using django-nonrel in any case. An extension to that, django-dbindexer, provides some support for emulating certain joins. But it's far from comprehensive. You generally need to architect your application in a different way to use the GAE datastore.